# Using "rewrite [hypothesis with implication]"

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Working through CIS 500 Software Foundations course[CIS 500 Software Foundations course](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/current/index.html). Currently on [MoreCoq](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis500/current/sf/MoreCoq.v). I don't understand the `rewrite IHl1` part. How is it working? Why does this not work when used before `simpl`?

```
Definition split_combine_statement : Prop := forall X Y (l1 : list X) (l2 : list Y),
  length l1 = length l2 -> split (combine l1 l2) = (l1,l2).

Theorem split_combine : split_combine_statement.
Proof. unfold split_combine_statement. intros. generalize dependent Y. induction l1. 
 Case "l = []". simpl. intros. destruct l2. 
  SCase "l2 = []". reflexivity. 
  SCase "l2 = y :: l2". inversion H.
 Case "l = x :: l1". intros.  destruct l2. 
  SCase "l2 = []". inversion H.
  SCase "l2 = y :: l2". simpl. rewrite IHl1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hypothesis `IHl1` is:

```
IHl1 : forall (Y : Type) (l2 : list Y),
       length l1 = length l2 -> split (combine l1 l2) = (l1, l2)
```

So in order to rewrite it, you need to instantiate the `Y` type and `l2` list. Next, you need to provide the equality `length l1 = length l2` to rewrite 
`split (combine l1 l2) = (l1,l2)`. The whole solution is:

```
Definition split_combine_statement : Prop := forall X Y (l1 : list X) (l2 : list Y),
  length l1 = length l2 -> split (combine l1 l2) = (l1,l2).

Theorem split_combine : split_combine_statement.
Proof. 
  unfold split_combine_statement. 
  intros. generalize dependent Y. induction l1. 
  simpl. intros. destruct l2. 
  reflexivity. 
  inversion H.
  intros.  destruct l2. 
  inversion H.
  simpl. inversion H. rewrite (IHl1 Y l2 H1). reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Note that to rewrite `IHl1`, we need to instantiate the universal quantifiers (passing adequate values for its variables) and to provide a left hand side for the implication. In Coq words: `rewrite (IHl1 Y l2 H1)` is passing the type `Y` to instantiate the `forall (Y : Type)` in `IHl1`. The same holds for `l2`.